# Set the enumeration index in one query or less queries

Tags: django

My question is I have this code.

```
reset_numbers = Picture.objects.filter(author__id=author.id)

for index, pic in enumerate(reset_numbers):
    pic.number = index
    pic.save()
```

I want to reset the ording of Pictures.
How I can do this in one query or less queries to get rid of the for loop?

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pks = Picture.objects.filter(author__id=author.id).values_list('pk', flat=True)
for index, pk in enumrate(pks):
    Picture.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(number=index)
```

This loads only primary keys, and only update `number` field. But query count is same as the original code.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization.